# Is one legally required to do anything if not billed for utilities?

Tags: california

I live in an apartment complex in California where electric and gas service are the tenant's responsibility.

When my tenancy began, I set up service with the local utility company. I went to their website today to check for this month's bill, and upon logging in I was told that my account is no longer active.

I didn't take any action to deactivate my account, and I haven't received any communication since an email notice that last month's bill had been generated.

If the utility company continues to provide service and doesn't contact me further, is there any possibility of me later being required to pay for the unbilled service? Am I acting maliciously by not informing the utility company of the apparent error? Can the utility company end service without notice?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe that there is a "statute of limitations" for old bills. The company can, however, "catch up" in the coming "months." I just don't know how many months the company is allowed to do this.

Comment: I don't think you would be liable in tort but they can cut it off any time they please if someone is not paying it